# Permanent call log?

Tags: call-history

Is there a way to have on Android a permanent call log which the user can't delete? (Or at least ask a password before deleting)

Either native (rooted phone so I can replace any system apk) or as a separate app which records the call details in a separate DB is fine

It would be best if this would work even on Android 2.3

Comment: Regularly backup and then make the file immutable (`chattr`) if the filesystem is ext2 or above.

Comment: But why do you want such feature? The real objective hasn't been revealed yet. Is this *user* a secondary user of your device or are you developing something?

Comment: I want this feature, as I will give this phone as a "convenience phone" for 1-2 days to friends visiting me. I just got burned by a huge bill made by someone who thought "hah, he will notice after one month". So I want to make clear to them: ok make calls, but I'll see how many, anf if you abuse that, you'll pay back. (For privacy the phone numbers can be censored, I just need how many and how long)

Comment: Well, you can try [Automatic Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder) which will save the call log as well as the recording and is not affected if the call entries gets deleted by a user in the dialer app. Also, **Settings -> Apps ->** the said app -> uncheck **show notifications**. Then use a custom launcher like [Smart Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ginlemon.flowerfree) to hide its icon and use [App Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=inno.applocker) to restrict access to settings by user.